# Find all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{b}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}}$ is Prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

Find all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$p=\frac{b}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}}$$is Prime

first of all $\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}$ should be perfect square so let it be $q^2$ where $q \in \mathbb{N}$

So  $$2p=bq$$ and since $2p$ is even atleast one of $b$ and $q$ should be even Natural number.

Let $b$ is even so $b=2k$ so we get

$$p=kq$$ but since $p$ is prime either $k=1$ and $q=p$ OR $q=1$ and $k=p$

any clue further?

Comment: Notice that $2a-b<2a+b$, so the expression under the square root is less than 1 and so it is not a positive integer.

Comment: @MatthewConroy That doesn't mean the entire expression can't be an integer. Take for instance $a=20$ and $b=24$.

Comment: Note $(a,b)=(10,12)$ is a solution, where the corresponding $p=3$.

Comment: @Mastrem Of course not.  However, the OP was assuming the expression had to be an integer when they said "let it be $q^2$ where $q \in  \mathbb{N}$" and I was pointing out this error in their argument. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$p=\frac{b}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}}=\frac b{2(2a+b)}\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}$$

So that we need $4a^2-b^2$ to be a square, say, $k^2$. But this means that $(2a)^2=b^2+k^2$, so that $(k,b,2a)$ is a pythagorean triple; this is good, because we know pythagorean triples are of the form $(2nm,n^2-m^2,n^2+m^2)$ (for $n>m$). Let's do a case split now:

---

**Case 1: $b=n^2-m^2$.** In this case, we have (by simply substituting $2a=n^2+m^2$ and $b=n^2-m^2$):

$$p=\frac{n^2m-m^3}{2n}$$

Let's split cases again: we know $2a=n^2+m^2$ so that either $n,m$ are both even or both odd.

**Case 1.1: $n,m$ are odd.** In this case, $p=\tfrac12(nm-\frac{m^3}{n})$ so that $\frac{m^3}{n}$ should be an integer. If there is no prime factor $q$ in $n$ with $q^3\mid n$, then $m\mid \frac{m^3}n$, so that $m\mid \tfrac12(nm-\frac{m^3}{n})$, or, $m\mid p$. There are now two sub-sub cases: $m=1$ and $m=p$, both are quickly checkable (both leading to $n=1$, from which a contradiction can be derived). Now we know there is a prime $q$ with $q^3\mid n$, and let us now write $n=q^3n_0$ and $m=qm_0$, making $p=\tfrac12(q^4n_0m_0-\frac{m_0^3}{n_0})$. This leads to $\frac{m_0^3}{n_0}$ being an integer, and this way, we see that we can repeat the process to see that $n$ has to be a perfect cube. Now let us write $n=N^3$ (and we see, $N\mid m$, so we write $m=MN$), and now we get $p=\tfrac12(N^4M-M^3)=\tfrac12M(N^2-M)(N^2+M)$. This being prime means $M=1$ (or $M=-1$, but this only changes the sign), which makes $p=\frac12(N-1)(N+1)(N^2+1)$, and since all three factors are divisible by $2$, this cannot be prime.

**Case 1.2: $n,m$ are even.** Write $p=\frac{nm}{2}-\frac{m^3}{2n}$ so that $\frac{m^3}{2n}$ has to be integer. We can do the same as we did in case 1.1 to show that $2n$ is a perfect cube. Now write $n=4N^3$ and $m=2NM$ to see that $p=M(2N^2-M)(2N^2+M)$, again meaning $M=1$ (and again, or $M=-1$, this only changes sign), so that $p=(2N^2-1)(2N^2+1)$, from which we deduce one of the terms has to be $\pm1$, so that $N\in\{-1,0,1\}$, and we see, $N=0$ results in $p=-1$ (not prime), but $N=-1$ and $N=1$ result in $p=3$. Now we go back and retrace our steps to get the corresponding $a,b$, and we see $(a,b)=(10,12)$ and that indeed results in $p=3$.

---

**Case 2: $b=2nm$.** Now, we have

$$p=nm-\frac{2nm^2}{n+m}$$

First, note that $\gcd(n,m)=1$; if not, find a prime $r\neq p$ with $n=rn_0$ and $m=rm_0$, so that $p=r^2\left(nm-\frac{2nm^2}{n+m}\right)$, meaning $r^2\mid p$, which is impossible for any prime $r$. For $p$ to be an integer however, we need $n+m\mid 2nm^2$; this means, for every odd prime $q\mid n+m$, we need $q\mid nm^2$, meaning $q\mid n$ or $q\mid m$, and since $q\mid n+m$, we know that both must be true: $q\mid n$ and $q\mid m$. Thus, $n+m$ doesn't have any odd prime factors, so it must be a power of $2$. Write $n=2^k-m$, so that we get

$$p=(2^k-m)m-\frac{(2^k-m)m^2}{2^{k-1}}=2^km-3m^2+\frac{m^3}{2^{k-1}}$$

So that $\frac{m^3}{2^{k-1}}$ has to be integer, so that we can write $m=2^lM$ with $3l\ge k-1$, obtaining

$$p=2^{k+l}M-3\cdot 2^{2l}M^2+2^{3l-k+1}M^3$$

this means $M\mid p$, so that $M=1$ or $M=p$. If $M=p$, then $1-2^{k+l}=2^{3l-k+1}p^2-3\cdot 2^{2l}p$

Now we have multiple cases (again).

**Case 2.1: $M=p$.** In this case, $1-2^{k+l}=2^{3l-k+1}p^2-3\cdot 2^{2l}p$. Now we have more subcases:

**Case 2.1.1: $l=0$.** Since $3l\ge k-1$, either $k=0$ or $k=1$; in the first case, $k=0$, we get $p=\frac32$, contradiction. In the second, $k=1$, we get $p^2-3p+1=0$ which obviously has no integer roots, a contradiction once again.

**Case 2.1.2: $l>0$.** Since the left-hand side of

$$1-2^{k+l}=2^{3l-k+1}p^2-3\cdot 2^{2l}p$$

is odd, we know the left-hand side is too: this means (since $2^{2l}$ is even for $l>0$) that $2^{3l-k+1}$ is odd (and so is $p$, ruling out $p=2$), so that $3l+1=k$, transforming the equation into $p^2-3\cdot 2^{2l}p+(2^{4l+1}-1)=0$, which is a quadratic in $p$, and since $p$ is an integer, the discriminant is a perfect square. The discriminant is

$$9\cdot 2^{4l}-4\cdot(2^{4l+1}-1)=2^2(2^{4l-2}-1)$$

meaning $2^{4l-2}-1$ is a square, but this is clearly impossible since $2^{4l-2}$ is a square itself and the only squares having difference $1$ are $0$ and $1$ (which in turn means $4l-2=0$, contradiction).

**Case 2.2: $M=1$.** The equation now reads

$$p=2^{k+l}-3\cdot 2^{2l}+2^{3l-k+1}$$

Again, we distinguish the same cases as in case 2.1;

**Case 2.2.1: $l=0$.** Now we again have $k=0$ or $k=1$; both of which yield $p=0$.

**Case 2.2.2: $l>0$.** I'm sorry, but we'll have to do another case split. Either $p=2$ (having $k< 3l+1$) or the right-hand side is odd (meaning $k=3l+1$):

**Case 2.2.2.1: $k<3l+1$.** We get

$$1=2^{k+l-1}-3\cdot 2^{2l-1}+2^{3l-k}$$

since the left-hand side is odd, one of the terms on the right is too: note however that $k+l-1=0$ and $2l-1=0$ are impossible for $k,l>0$. Thus, $3l=k$, and substitution yields (after rewriting) $3=2^{2l}$, obviously impossible.

**Case 2.2.2.2: $k=3l+1$.** Now substitution yields

$$p=2^{4l+1}-3\cdot 2^{2l}+1$$

and looking at this $\mod 3$ tells us

\begin{align}
p&\equiv 2^{4l+1}-3\cdot 2^{2l}+1\\
&\equiv -1\cdot (-1)^{4l}-0\cdot 2^{2l}+1\\
&\equiv -1+1\\
&\equiv 0\mod 3
\end{align}

resulting in $p=3$, the only prime divisible by $3$. Now all that's left is solving $3=2^{4l+1}-3\cdot 2^{2l}+1$, but rewriting quickly results in $1=2^{4l}-3\cdot 2^{2l-1}$, which is a contradiction since the left is odd and the right is even.